# Magento: displaying associated product's image on configurable product

Tags: php, javascript, magento, product

I'd like to have my configurable product's image change when I select a different simple product using the dropdown in Magento. I've tried following [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/change_product_image_on_view_page_to_associated_product_s_image), but it has no effect at all (and no errors, fyi). Can anyone assist me in a finding a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial works on the latest version of magento I recently used the same method to achieve that, you might want to try using the following module:

https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

Among the many feature it adds changing the configurable product image its included.

Also if you want to use the tutorial method, I recommend that you:

- Use firefox and install:

  - Firebug
  - FirePHP
  - FireLogger

Check for Javascript errors and use the Firebug Console to see if you are properly setting the js vars.

Answer (score 1):

Magento CE 1.9 has default feature for it Check below Thread

[Change product image for configurable products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/change-product-image-for-configurable-products)

For Prgramatically changing the image you can check Below Thread

[How to change configurable product main image by associated product image based on color and size attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299592/how-to-change-configurable-product-main-image-by-associated-product-image-based)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this new module, does a lot more then scp

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sdocp-simple-details-on-configurable-products.html